# How to find CMI Provider for a BRANCH TYPE in Clearcase using lsprovider command?

Tags: clearcase

Using mkcmprovider command in CLEARCASE 8.x, I can attach a CMI Provider to a BRANCH TYPE object.

Question is:

how do I list the attached CMI Provider for a particular BRANCH TYPE object using lsprovider command?

Comment: I am using BASE CLEARCASE only and no UCM according to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21641361

Comment: [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21641361)

Comment: Also this link
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633122

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'lsprovider -pname' option and supply a version whose leaf branch is an instance of the branch type you're interested in.  For example, if "myfile" in your view selects "myfile@@/main/mybranch/14", 'lsprovider' will list the CMI Provider info for the branch type, "mybranch".

For more information, see the ClearCase Knowledge Center:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsprovider.htm

Answer (score 0):

I can see some examples in "[How to configure ClearCase UCM to use the Change Management Integration with RTC](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21640748)"

Considering the syntax is:

> `lsprovider [-long]{[-vob vob-selector[,...]] [-replica replica-selector[,...]] [-pname pname[,...]] [-stream stream-name[,...]}`

That means the only way to link that command to a brtype is to use the sright stream name (attached to the branch you want) in your `lsprovider` command: `-stream stream-name`.

Answer (score 0):

A new 'cleartool' command line option to 'lsprovider' was added in 8.0.0.15 and 8.0.1.08, '-brtype'.  It allows you to specify the branch type whose provider(s) you wish to see.

The ClearCase Information Center has the details:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsprovider.htm

The updated command line syntax is:

**lsprovider [ –long ] { [ –vob vob-selector[,...] ] [ –replica replica-selector[,...] ] [ –pname pname[,...] ] [ –brtype brtype_name, ... ] ] [ –stream stream-name[,...] ] }**

Comment: Can you please tell me the IBM Link for 8.0.0.15 or 8.0.1.08 where it is mentioned -brtype option as new feature? I am having 8.0.1.7 right now. I will as ADMIN to install the newer version once I justify to them with the IBM link for -brtype option.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27045000  The above link doesn't show that -brtype option was added in lsprovider command. It shows that CMI enhancements have been done